# Using Excel VBA To Hide Rows Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

Alright...back again with another Excel question.

This time around, I have an Excel workbook which has the chemical and physical properties of 800 chemicals/compounds.  I have another workbook that has about 200 of these chemicals.

What I need to do in the workbook with the 800 chemicals is only display the chemicals that are displayed in the smaller workbook.  I could technically go through all 800 chemicals and use the "Filter" function to deselect everything I don't want, but obviously that would take forever and there is surely a faster way.

**Heres what I'm thinking needs to happen:**

In both workbooks, CAS number is one of the columns.  I have copied all of the CAS numbers for the chemicals I ***want*** to have displayed into a new column in the larger workbook.  What I would like to do is have some VBA code that basically says this: "If the CAS number in the larger workbook equals the CAS number in the smaller workbook, display that chemical.  If it doesn't, then don't display it.

If that's difficult to understand then I apologize, it's tough to put into words.

```
This is what I started doing:

    Sub HideRows()

    BeginRow = 3
    EndRow = 802
    ChkCol = 3

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow

        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "A3" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        Next RowCnt


    End Sub
```

I don't think that's right though.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Place this routine in a standard code module.

```
Public Sub Ryan_C()

    Dim rCrit As Range, rData As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1").[a1]
        Set rData = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, .Item(, .Parent.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2").[a1]
        Set rCrit = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rCrit

End Sub
```

Note: this assumes the 800 chemical compounds are in Sheet1 and the 200 CAS Registry numbers are in Sheet2. Edit the sheet names as needed.

Note: this assumes the data in both sheets begin in cell A1.

Note: IT ALSO ASSUMES THAT THE CAS HEADER AT THE TOP OF BOTH SHEETS MATCH.

Comment: @findwindow With the AdvancedFilter, absolutely.

Comment: @Ryan_C Do you need help getting this going? Please let me know.

Comment: @ExcelHero I'm still thinking of a better way to phrase the question.  There are a lot of variables going on that make this hard phrase properly.

Comment: @Ryan_C Fair enough, but I think my solution clearly answers the question posed. Please remember that Stack Overflow is a resource for future visitors seeking help with their questions as well. If you have a differently worded question, please post that as a new question, and accept this answer.